# Gitlab pages CI/CD pipeline is passing but resulting page don't load resources

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Here is the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - apt-get update
  - apt-get install -y nodejs npm  # install NPM in order to build the website
  - npm install
  - npm run build                  # build the website
  - mv dist public                 # move the built website to the public directory
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```

The pipeline pass, i.e. the jobs `pages` and `pages:deploy` are passing. Also the website is correctly built: when I download the artifacts, all ressources are presents in the `public` directory.

However, when I look to the [generated website](https://cl00e9ment.gitlab.io/kingdom-blazon-generator/), the index.html is loading but all ressources aren't (404 code).

Here is the repo: https://gitlab.com/Cl00e9ment/kingdom-blazon-generator

Answer (score 0):

GitLab's pages only support static webpages, but not dynamic webpages. This means that you can't run servers like `node.js`, but only generate HTML and other static files.

You can read more about it here:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/#overview

Comment: I'm not running a Node.js server. I'm using Node.js to generate the static pages (and it works well: when I download the artifacts everything is here). Then I move the generated pages into the `public` directory and I let Gitlab handle the rest.

Comment: Ah, I see. That's what I get for trying to answer questions too quickly! I tried to download the artifacts from your linked repository, and it looks the exact same way as on GitLab. If you read your generated `index.html`, then you have lines like `Loading...` and `An error has occured:`. If you read through your gitlab pages job, you have some warnings from npm. Something seems to not be working as you want it to when you generate the page.

Comment: Ok my bad. I just found out that the problem come from the fact that the URLs start with a `/` but the Gitlab pages aren't hosted on the root.

Comment: So many hours lost for just a basic mistake... Thanks for your help nevertheless.

Comment: It is almost always the basic mistakes that gets us! Good to hear that you figured it out in the end, and always happy to help.